# Comparing two files and printing the content

Tags: text-processing

I want to compare two files and want the output with the unique contents of both files + common content from the first file.

Example :-

File A.txt

```
A=x
B=y
C=z
```

File B.txt

```
A=p
D=q
E=r
```

Output :-

```
A=x
B=y
C=z
D=q
E=r
```

Kindly help me in resolving this.
I want to perform this on Linux server so any command or shell script for this.

Comment: How is `A=p` not unique?

Comment: Yes that's the Problem statement.
The values will be different of the common Key's in both the files.
So I want that from the first file.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain that you want us to consider this as a file with two fields, where fields are defined by `=`. Then, explain that you want only the unique 1st fields. how in the world did you expect us to understand this from your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `awk`:

```
$ awk -F= '{a[$1]++; if(a[$1]==1){print}}' A.txt B.txt  
A=x
B=y
C=z
D=q
E=r
```

#### Explanation

- `a[$1]++;` : saves the 1st field as a key in the array `a` and increments the value associated with that key by one. This means that the first time a key is seen (for example, the first `A=x`), the value will be 1 but the second it will be 2. This lets us count unique elements.
- `if(a[$1]==1){print}` : if the first field has only been seen once, print.

Because we're processing `B.txt` after `A.txt`, the values in `A.txt` are the ones that are kept.

Comment: can we do this with `diff` ?

Comment: Thanks but I don't want the A=p in the output.
if there are same content in both the file then the content from 1st file should come not from second.

Comment: @ArpitGupta then please edit your question and add a correct example. You say you want all unique lines from both files and `A=p` is unique: it's only in the second file. Do you mean that you only want the unique letters before the `=`?

Comment: @terdon Sorry for that.
So the Problem is we have A= in both the files. 
But I want the value of A= from the first file it should skip the common lines from the second one and take them from the first.

Comment: @ArpitGupta it's OK, but please ***[edit]*** your question to clarify. Also, see updated answer.

Comment: @terdon Thanks for the help and Command.
This command works for me.